# Publish an uint8_t as char over MQTT on Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, mqtt, esp32

DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1

```
uint8_t  boardTempByte[12];
String   boardTemp;
```

in loop

```
Lidar1.read(0xE0, boardTempByte, 1, 0x62); //Board Temeperature

boardTemp = boardTempByte[0];
      
Serial.println(boardTemp);
```

Serial print give to me the right value, but:

```
client.publish("lidar1/temp", boardTemp);
```

give to me error:
PubSubClient::publish(const char [12], String&)
no known conversion for argument 2 from 'String' to 'const char*'

So, I must do some type of conversion, but is over my understanding

Comment: Ah, got it:
client.publish("lidar1/temp", boardTemp.c_str());

Comment: Yes, you're right: I must study c++.